# Как изменить цвет выделения найденных после поиска слов?

Tags: vim

Уже давно хотел изменить цвет выделения найденных слов с желтого (глаза режет) на светло-зеленый или пурпурный к примеру. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполните вот такую команду.

```
:highlight Search ctermbg=LightGreen guibg=LightGreen
```

Это изменит фоновый цвет знакомест для подсветки совпадающих кусков текста для посленего состоявшегося поиска на светло-зелёный. Вариант подходит не только для обычного вим, запущенного в терминале, но и для gVim.